# How to use eval to run other python script with argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, eval

I have a python file a.py containing code:

```
var=50*10
data= # eval here to call add function of b.py with argument var
print(data)
```

and b.py contains code :

```
def add(h):
    res=h+10
    return res
```

Now what i want is to use eval to call run function of b.py from a.py python script with argument and get the result.
but i am not able to understand how eval works here. I had looked at python official docs and they are beyond my understanding.
or if not eval then what are the other options (except using other file as module)

Comment: The usual thing to do would be to `import b` and do `data = b.add(var)` - you never need eval to do anything.

Comment: yes i know importing file as module can work but any other way that can help?

Comment: Do you have any issues with importing? Maybe we could try to solve that problem instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval()` is a method for *evaluation* of [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) only. Thus, you can't use other [statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html). Since `import` is a statement, you can't use it in `eval()`.

> what are the other options (except using other file as module)

[`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) works together with import, so a combination of `exec()` and `eval()` works:

```
var = 50 * 10
exec("import b")
data = eval("b.add(var)")
print(data)
```

Or even `exec()` without `eval()`:

```
var = 50 * 10
exec("import b\ndata=b.add(var)")
print(data)
```

Note:

- IDEs may likely complain that `data` is undefined in the last version of the code
- `exec()` is even more dangerous than `eval()`

Answer (score -2):

you only needs to write like this :)) <3

```
def add(h):
    res=h+10
    return res

var=50*10

data = eval('add(var)')
print(data)
```

Comment: but my function is in different file